# Is there a way to get drag and drop data in safari 11 or is that broken?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I created an webpage that lets users drag and drop images from a website into a div.

If I drag an image of a potato from google images into the box of this webpage , the image's url should get logged to the jconsole.

This works perfectly in windows but not on mac.

Using safari 11 on mac, `getData` never returns anything

Using Chrome on mac, `getData` only returns with text/html

using Firefox on mac, `getData` returns both text/plain and text/html

I'm fine with chrome and firefox.

My problem is that getData never returns anything no matter what I have tried so far.

Code:

```js
function dragenterhandle(elem, event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("DragEnter Called\n");
  return true;
}

function dragoverhandle(elem, event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //console.log("Dragover Called\n");
  return true;
}

function ondrophandle(elem, event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("ondrop Called\n");
  var a = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  console.log("Value of a:\n" + a);
}

function dragstarthandler(event) {
  console.log("dragstart Called\n");
  event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "all";
  return true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .img-bx {
      border-style: dashed;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 500px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='img-bx' ondragenter="dragenterhandle(this, event);" ondragover="dragoverhandle(this, event);" ondrop="ondrophandle(this, event);" ondragstart="dragstarthandler(event);">
  </div>
  <script src="eng.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I see the same log messages when I drag a GIF in both Safari 11 and Chrome 63. "DragEnter Called", "onDrop Called", "Value of a:". There's no value shown in either case.

Comment: I used the GIF at https://media.giphy.com/media/CwbErAWpTQDxS/giphy.gif in my test.

Comment: Thankyou for having a look, and yeah that is an expected result. 
modify the line `var a = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");` to say
`var a = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");` and you should get a result in chrome.

Comment: Why would an image have type `text/html`?

Comment: The DnD Data does. It seems to take the whole element with it. Here is an example output when the datatype is set to text/html

Value of a:
`<img style="-webkit-user-select: none;background-position: 0px 0px, 10px 10px;background-size: 20px 20px;background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, #eee 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #eee 75%, #eee 100%),linear-gradient(45deg, #eee 25%, white 25%, white 75%, #eee 75%, #eee 100%);cursor: zoom-in;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/Russet_potato_cultivar_with_sprouts.jpg" width="958" height="483">`